How to implement a custom LSTM cell in PyTorch
I am trying to build a custom LSTM cell. I found many snippets online but none of them produces same result as torch lstm. For testing, I fix input size and number of layers to 1. Is there a known way how to customise the weights inside an LSTM cell or is there a pythonic way to write it even not efficient. Here is how I tried
First LSTM cell
class LSTMCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, input_size=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weight_ih = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, input_size))
        self.weight_hh = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, hidden_size))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(4 * hidden_size))
        
    def forward(self, x, hx=None, cx=None):
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.size()        
        outputs = []
        for t in range(seq_len):
            x_t = x[:, t, :]  # Extract the t-th time step

            # Compute gates
            gates = (x_t @ self.weight_ih.T) + (hx @ self.weight_hh.T) + self.bias
            i_gate, f_gate, g_gate, o_gate = gates.chunk(4, dim=1)
            
            # Activation functions for gates
            input_gate = torch.sigmoid(i_gate)
            forget_gate = torch.sigmoid(f_gate)
            cell_gate = torch.tanh(g_gate)
            output_gate = torch.sigmoid(o_gate)
            
            # Update cell state and hidden state
            cx = (forget_gate * cx) + (input_gate * cell_gate)
            hx = output_gate * torch.tanh(cx)

            # Append the current hidden state to outputs
            outputs.append(hx.unsqueeze(1))  # Add time dimension back

        # Concatenate outputs along the time dimension
        outputs = torch.cat(outputs, dim=1)
        return outputs, (hx, cx)

Second, here is how it is combined with dense layer
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers=1):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        
        self.LSTMModel = LSTMCell(hidden_size=self.hidden_size) 
        #nn.LSTM(1, hidden_size, 1, batch_first=True, bias=True) #uncomment to compare with LSTM
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size, bias=False)
        
        # Initialize states
        self.tracked_h = None
        self.tracked_c = None

    def reset_states(self, batch_size):
        """Reset the hidden and cell states to zero."""
        self.tracked_c = torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_size) 
        self.tracked_h = torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_size) 

    def adjust_states_for_batch_size(self, batch_size):
        """Adjust the tracked states if the batch size changes."""
        if self.tracked_h is not None:
            if self.tracked_h.size(0) < batch_size:  # Batch size increased, reset states
                self.reset_states(batch_size)
            elif self.tracked_h.size(0) > batch_size:  # Batch size decreased, slice states
                self.tracked_h = self.tracked_h[:batch_size, :]
                self.tracked_c = self.tracked_c[:batch_size, :]
        else:
            self.reset_states(batch_size)

    def forward(self, x, h=None, c=None):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        
        self.adjust_states_for_batch_size(batch_size)

        out,(h,cn)= self.LowRankCell(x,hx=self.tracked_h,cx=self.tracked_c)
        
        # Update tracked states
        self.tracked_h = h.detach()
        self.tracked_c = c.detach()    
        output = torch.tanh(self.fc(h))
        return output
    


The LSTM cell implementation is from CUDNN, you can't change it. At best, you can write your own implementation of nn.LSTMCell, write a LSTM class that loops over the sequence length in python, and torch jit compile it for performance. Note that pytorch's nn.LSTMCell only processes a single time step at a time, in contrast to your implementation
